# When do permissions `allowFileDiscovery` in the Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

Files in Google Drive can be permissioned to allow anyone in a domain or on the internet with the link to view or edit.
However, these files are usually not considered "public" as people may share links privately without intending for the file to be readily discoverable (even if this is not very secure), and so they are not discoverable by search.

The [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions) exposes a field `allowFileDiscovery` which suggests it's possible to change this behavior:

> Whether the permission allows the file to be discovered through search. This is only applicable for permissions of type `domain` or `anyone`.

However, `allowFileDiscovery` seems to always be false. Is there any situation where `allowFileDiscovery` would be true? Is it possible to set this flag via the API in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is based on my experience with several replications I have tried using the '***REST Resource: permissions***'.

By default, all files created or uploaded in My Drive or shared folders have the `allowFileDiscovery` set to ***false***. Additionally, when you manually change a file's "**General access**" option from **Restricted** *(**default**)* to **All users under a domain** *(**domain**)* or **Anyone with a link** *(**anyone**)* using the Google Drive web interface, the value will still be ***false***.

---

**Questions**

1. **Is there any situation where** `allowFileDiscovery` would be true?
2. **Is it possible to set this flag via the API in any way?**

> **Yes**, there is one situation in which files/folders will have the `allowFileDiscovery` set to a true value, and this will only occur through the Drive API.

---

**Sample Demo**

- ***E.g.*** Say you have this file w/ **General access** manually set to **domain** type.

[image]

 *(**file id**: 1Wk54WwVuIaGVugBsvp3lSDw0spLljvt2)*

---

- When you list the file's permissions using the `permissions.list` method, you'll notice that its `allowFileDiscovery` would still be ***false*** from the result:

[image]

---

- Now, for the file to have the `allowFileDiscovery` set to ***true***, this will be accomplished through the `permissions.create` method with the following sample request body:

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

- After the request, here's the result:

[image]

---

- Then, when you once again list the file's permissions using the `permissions.list` method, the `allowFileDiscovery` of the file is now set to ***true***:

[image]

> **Note**: It appears that updating the file's `allowFileDiscovery` using the **Method: permissions.update** won't be possible, as it would result in a `"fieldNotWritable"` error.

---

### References

- [Method: permissions.list (with API explorer)](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions/list)
- [Method: permissions.create (with API explorer)](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions/create)

Comment: Thank you. It is strange that this is only achievable through the Drive API and is otherwise inaccessible to users.

Comment: As of this morning, I've noticed there is an option in the share GUI on google drive labeled "Can find in search results" when sharing with a domain, and so it appears this was just addressed.